# rails 4 rbenv Mavericks cannot install Nokogiri 1.6.3 , insane error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, osx-mavericks, rbenv

I trying for hours ( now days...) to install Nokogiri 1.6.3   I thought I could do it a sstated on Nokogiri site ( http://nokogiri.org/tutorialsinstalling_nokogiri.html) but it's failing , requiring development tool installation...

```
/Users/yves/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': 
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/yves/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
```

I am using XCode 5.1 , and dev tools is installed !  otherwise I could not install the libiconv library ...

```
yves$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   ...


  yves$ gcc -v
  Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
   Thread model: posix
```

I went through all questions/answers related to this issue ( many cases , many given solutions;.. ) but none works for Nokogiri 1.6.3 ( latest update)

just for counterchecking , I tried installing the gem ffi which need also to build native extensions , and it's fine ...

```
yves$ gem install ffi
Fetching: ffi-1.9.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.3
1 gem installed
```

Comment: seems to be definitely a Nokogiri 1.6.3 gem install issue ... I finally installed 1.6.2.1 wo any trouble and locked it ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is Nokgiri 1.6.3 dependency issue. Try the following:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2  --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Before doing this, make sure that correct versions of libxml2, libxslt and libiconv are installed in your system and the above paths are correct as well.